# React router route clash with optional param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't visit `dashboard/job/123/status`, I guess it has clashes?

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/dashboard/job/:jobId/:notificationId?"
  component={Jobs}
/>
<Route exact path="/dashboard/job/:jobId/status" component={JobStatusContainer} />
```

Comment: If you put the `/dashboard/job/:jobId/status` route before your other route, does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kyle mentioned, you need to reverse the order of your routes.

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard/job/:jobId/status" component={JobStatusContainer} />
<Route
  exact
  path="/dashboard/job/:jobId/:notificationId?"
  component={Jobs}
/>
```

The order you have it, `dashboard/job/123/status` is being consumed by `/dashboard/job/:jobId/:notificationId?` path and never reaching the check for the `/dashboard/job/:jobId/status` path, because it thinks you want `status` to be the value of `:notificationId`